# Which control should I use to display an ActionSheet-like view at the top of the screen?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I was asked to display a list of three options for the user in a View sliding from the top to bottom. They say it should slide from the top because the action is initiated from a dropdown-like button on the navigation bar.

Most of what I found on that subject mentions the deprecated `UIActionSheet` class.

The "new" way using `UIAlertController` doesn't seem to allow us to change position of the view. At the least from what I've found.

The end result I'm trying to get can be seen on the image below,

[image: Sample]

From what I've learned about iOS programming, one method I could think to achieve that would be to create a new UIViewController and to use a custom class to control the transition. But it just seems so much. And I think it wouldn't not look like a dropdown afterall.

The other option would be to create the TableView with options and leave it on the Controller where it should be displayed, configuring its height to zero. And then Animating when necessary. I also have such a bad feeling doing it this way.

Is there a right way to do this on iOS? Does one of the options I've found seems acceptable?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually - both do. Personally I'd go for the separate view controller, to keep code cleaner. There is also a lot of results for "dropdown" on cocoapods, maybe one of them will fit your needs - https://cocoapods.org/?q=Dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion given by @Losiowaty on the comments, I started looking for a custom View/Control on cocoapods and ended up finding quite a few that did what I was looking.

The one I decided to use is this:
https://github.com/lminhtm/LMDropdownView